# Twilio Studio Flow HTTP Request Failed with Status code 500

Tags: get, twilio, twilio-php

I am working with Twilio Flow to create a WhatsApp Chat bot.

This bot allows user to start chat and respond with specific terms or numbers to proceed. It works fine, now I have added "Make HTTP Request" WIDGET to call an URL for posting the data received in response to DB.

When the HTTP Request is made, it returns FAIL & SUCCESS for some reasons,
On checking logs, i found out that a URL when any parameter is without any space or any special character, HTTP request gets success with Response code 200, but when its more than a word with added space or any special character HTTP request is failed and returned with Response code 500.

HTTP Request URL :

> [https://websiteurl.com/page.php?whatsapp_number={{contact.channel.address}}&message={{widgets.ReplyReceived5.inbound.Body}}](https://websiteurl.com/page.php?whatsapp_number=%7B%7Bcontact.channel.address%7D%7D&message=%7B%7Bwidgets.ReplyReceived5.inbound.Body%7D%7D)

I also tried to make HTTP Request to https://webhook.site, but it also failed.

Added SUCCESS and FAILED Request Screenshot below.

Any help to fix this?

[Image of HTTP Request getting SUCCESS with response code 200, Message parameter in URL without any space or special character](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hriub.png)

[Image of HTTP Request FAILED with response code 500, Message parameter in URL with space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpbM4.png)

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

In Studio, you can use HTTP Params and `GET` which will do the encoding (to handle spaces) for you. Or, you could use [Liquid Filtering](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/url_encode/) like `{{ widgets.boop.di.doop | url_encode }}`. My amazing coworker and Studio wizard Craig Dennis recommends using HTTP params.

Let me know if this helps at all!

Comment: Thanks @lizziepika. Liquid filtering was something i was looking for. It worked like charm :)

Comment: Yay @ShubhamJain! If it helped, do mark as answer please :) <3